# How to split sentence to words and punctuation using split or matcher?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, text, split

I need to split sentence to words and punctuation marks, and place em into list, saving their sequence.

***For example:*** `"Some text here!"`. And result should be: `List(Some, ,text, , here,!)`

I'm using `String.split("regex");` With "split" I can split text only by word or only by punctuation.

So what should I use, to split text by words and punctuation at same time?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what if there are some digits? .. `some text2 here! 4 you`?

Comment: digits belong to words. It's like to split words from non word characters.

Comment: Now I only can split string to words and add them to list. Like  String[] words = sentenseToParse.split(regex); But I also need to get non word characters like !@#$ from same string (including spaces). And place em to String[] sentenseParts. It's should be like {word, space, another word, dot}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on

> And result should be: List(`Some, ,text, , here,!)`

it looks like you want to split on [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `split("\\b")`.

```
String data = "Some text here!";
for (String s : data.split("\\b")){
    System.out.println("'"+s+"'");
}
```

Output:

```
'Some'
' '
'text'
' '
'here'
'!'
```

Comment: yes, that's what I need. Ill try it out now. Thank you! And sorry for my stupid question)

Comment: That kind of complicates things too much to be answered in this question. Consider [posting another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in which you will describe precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also try to avoid [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank u. I will. I realise that I ducked up with question.