# How to split a sentence into words and punctuations in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a given sentence of type string into words and I also want punctuation to be added to the list.

For example, if the sentence is: **"Sara's dog 'bit' the neighbor."** 

 I want the output to be: **[Sara's, dog, ', bit, ', the, neighbour, .]**

With string.split(" ") I can split the sentence in words by space, but I want the punctuation also to be in the result list.

```
    String text="Sara's dog 'bit' the neighbor."  
    String list = text.split(" ")
    the printed result is [Sara's, dog,'bit', the, neighbour.]
    I don't know how to combine another regex with the above split method to separate punctuations also.
```

Some of the reference I have already tried but didn't work out

1.[Splitting strings through regular expressions by punctuation and whitespace etc in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384791/splitting-strings-through-regular-expressions-by-punctuation-and-whitespace-etc)

2.[How to split sentence to words and punctuation using split or matcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255842/how-to-split-sentence-to-words-and-punctuation-using-split-or-matcher)

Example input and outputs

```
String input1="Holy cow! screamed Jane."

String[] output1 = [Holy,cow,!,screamed,Jane,.] 

String input2="Select your 'pizza' topping {pepper and tomato} follow me."

String[] output2 = [Select,your,',pizza,',topping,{,pepper,and,tomato,},follow,me,.]
```

Comment: One solution is to write a custom function to do this.

Comment: do you have any reference for a sample like this?

Comment: No reference is needed. You have to come up with it yourself. If I were solving this problem, I would start by turning off my computer. Then I would get a notebook and a pen and write down **in words** the steps I need to take to solve the problem. Once I have a clear idea of those steps, then I would translate those words into Java.

Comment: Translating from a language of people to a language of the machine is a large part of the job of a computer programmer. This requires the first step of explaining the solution in natural human language.

Comment: Ii both the example it becomes three elements. I have edited the question. 'bit' will become [',bit,'] also the word 'pizza' will become [',pizza,']

Comment: @Abra In the first part, *'bit'` is also 3 elements. You're incorrectly looking at the code block, which shows OP failed attempts, not a desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to come up with a pattern to split on, this challenge is easier to solve by coming up with a pattern of the elements to capture.

Although it's more code than a simple `split()`, it can still be done in a single statement in Java 9+:

```
String regex = "[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}]+(?:\\p{P}[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}]+)*|[\\p{P}\\p{S}]";
String[] parts = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s).results().map(MatchResult::group).toArray(String[]::new);
```

In Java 8 or earlier, you would write it like this:

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    parts.add(m.group());
}
```

*Explanation*

`\p{L}` is Unicode *letters*, `\\p{N}` is Unicode *numbers*, and `\\p{M}` is Unicode *marks* (e.g. accents). Combined, they are here treated as characters in a "word".

`\p{P}` is Unicode *punctuation*. A "word" can have single punctuation characters embedded *inside* the word. The pattern before `|` matches a "word", given that definition.

`\p{S}` is Unicode *symbol*. Punctuation that is not embedded inside a "word", and symbols, are matched individually. That is the pattern after the `|`.

That leaves Unicode categories `Z` (*separator*) and `C` (*other*) uncovered, which means that any such character is skipped.

*Test*

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("Sara's dog 'bit' the neighbor.");
        test("Holy cow! screamed Jane.");
        test("Select your 'pizza' topping {pepper and tomato} follow me.");
    }
    private static void test(String s) {
        String regex = "[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}]+(?:\\p{P}[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}]+)*|[\\p{P}\\p{S}]";
        String[] parts = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s).results().map(MatchResult::group).toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
[Sara's, dog, ', bit, ', the, neighbor, .]
[Holy, cow, !, screamed, Jane, .]
[Select, your, ', pizza, ', topping, {, pepper, and, tomato, }, follow, me, .]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.stream( s.split("((?<=[\\s\\p{Punct}])|(?=[\\s\\p{Punct}]))") )
.filter(ss -> !ss.trim().isEmpty())
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Reference:

[How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206378/how-to-split-a-string-but-also-keep-the-delimiters)

[Regular Expressions on Punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705112/regular-expressions-on-punctuation)

Comment: If using Java 11+, `ss.trim().isEmpty()` can be shortened to `ss.isBlank()`

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<String>();
String str = "Hello my name is bob";
String tempStr = "";
for(String cha : str.toCharArray()){
  if(cha.equals(" ")){
    chars.add(tempStr);
    tempStr = "";
  }
  //INPUT WHATEVER YOU WANT FOR PUNCTATION WISE
  else if(cha.equals("!") || cha.equals(".")){
    chars.add(cha);
  }
  else{
    tempStr = tempStr + cha;
  }
}
chars.add(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

That?
It should add every single word, assuming there is spaces for each word in the sentence. for !'s, and .'s, you would have to do a check for that as well. Quite simple.

Comment: In what way does that handle **punctuation**, which is the main problem posed in the question?

Comment: Done, either way the other respondent provided a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, I even missed that that code doesn't even compile.